# Emulator crash "Invalid int"

Tags: java, android

I have become stuck in my code and I can not procced.The emulator crashes and the stack points to line 47. Please  help a beginner out!

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        Button obutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.obutton);
        obutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lista);
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();



            final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                if (edt.getText().toString() != null) {
                    adapter.addItem(edt.getText().toString());
                }
                }
            });
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        private List mIdMap;


        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.data = (ArrayList) objects;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            String item = getItem(position);
            return (long) mIdMap.get(Integer.parseInt(item)) <-- Crashing 
        }

        public void addItem(String item) {
            data.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.obutton:
                Intent obama = new Intent(MainActivity3.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(obama);
            case R.id.button:
                Intent test = new Intent(MainActivity3.this, Main6Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(test, 1);

        }

    }


}
```

The Stack error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:
>   "t"   at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer Chirag! However I cannot simply code "get(item)" or even get (String new (item)). Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return (long) mIdMap.get(Integer.parseInt(item)) <-- Crashing
```

to:
 @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return -1l;
Made it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing invalid integer. String should contains numeric number only to parse it as int.

Currently you are parsing "t" as integer, so you are getting error. Item should be like "0", "1" or any numeric number string.

Comment: Just to clarify, I know what the problem IS however i dont know how to solve it. Should i perhaps change my variable mIDMap from list so something more appropriate?